# Automatically update UVs when changing mesh

Tags: uv, sculpting

Is there a way in Blender to automatically update the UVs when performing modifications on mesh?
I have a model which I UV unwrapped. I then enter sculpt mode and make slight modifications to the mesh. But the UVs are not altered based on any changes made after unwrapping. This is causing slight stretching of the UVs. 
I don't want to have to re-unwrap the model. Is there a way in Blender for the UV map to remain in-sync with any changes to the mesh?

Comment: No, I don't think there is, at least as far as I know. This is one of the main reasons I hate UV unwrapping so much and prefer whenever possible to use procedural textures and generated texture coordinates instead. Some operators do support this like *Edge Slide* and *Vertex Slide* family of tools, but support is limited to very few operators.

Comment: So it looks like the best solution is to select the vertices in the UV editor and choose UVs->Minimize Stretch?

Comment: Either that or unwrap only when you are done with modelling, as close as possible to final shape. Otherwise unwrap from scratch